# How to show a page loader in laravel after submitting my form

Tags: php, laravel

How to display a loader after form submit in laravel, i am currently using css for this option...but its not working as expected.

```
 <button type="submit" id="submit" class="w-full px-3 py-3 font-medium text-white bg-green-400 rounded-lg">Request now</button>
```

Comment: Did you do any research? You can find tutorials about it on Google.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector(".mybtn").addEventListener('click', myfunction);
var loader = document.querySelector(".myloader");
var contents = document.querySelector(".pageContents");
loader.style.display = "none";

function myfunction() {

  loader.style.display = "block";
  contents.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.myloader {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("https://media3.giphy.com/media/KG4PMQ0jyimywxNt8i/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47uqzqe9qit5cdf4u7y9fqsw10slzt251h73nx9qri&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.pageContents {
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="pageContents container bg-success">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="m-5 p-2 btn btn-primary rounded-pill mybtn">Request now</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myloader container-fluid">
  </div>


</body>
```

> Run in fullscreen. To make loading gif to stay longer, use Javascript to set a delay before form submission.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this is what you need. But I also hope to help you:

```
<form action="you_action" method="post">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="w-full px-3 py-3 font-medium text-white bg-green-400 rounded-lg">Request now</button>
</form>
```

**Method:** *post or get*

**Action:** *Is the link to the page you want to go to when you press submit*